# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2

Tags: android, azure-devops, android-gradle-plugin

I am following the steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops

I have created a pipeline, requested an increase to free parallelism in Azure DevOps which was approved, created a Wear OS app on my local machine, and am trying to build it in the pipeline. However, the pipeline is failing with the below message

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
```

My pipeline file is quite simple:

```
# Android
# Build your Android project with Gradle.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute the APK, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/android

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleDebug'
```

Any idea how to resolve this, besides downgrading my project gradle plugin version?

Comment: Can you build your project successfully on your local machine?  What are your local gradle and java version?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Yes I can. I have Gradle 8.2 and Android Gradle plug-in 8.2.2. My Java version is "1.8.0_391"

Comment: Can you try to add the argument:     `javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'`
  `jdkVersionOption: '1.8'` to the Gradle@2 task to set the java version to 1.8 and have a try ?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Just did. Same error message. I've updated the question to reflect the complete error message.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I think I made a mistake. Looks like Android Studio uses OpenJDK embedded in JBR. The binary's version is 17.0.7.0 and `java -version` from that folder returns [openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18]

Comment: No Problem. I can reproduce the similar issue when using  com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.  You can refer to the answer and check if it can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8

Based on the error message, the com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 requires java 11 or later version.

We can set the argument: `jdkVersionOption: '1.17'` in Gradle@2 task.

For example:

```
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleDebug'
  displayName: gradlew assembleDebug test
```

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.

Based on the old error message, it seems that the gradle:8.2.2 is not able to be found from the resource set in the project.

To solve this issue, you can add the `google()` to the repositories in **build.gradle** file.

For example：

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google() 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: The first part was the correct answer. The message about Android Gradle plug-in not being resolved was due to it not being loaded. Might be worth updating the documentation as I am using an out of the box Android Studio installation.